# iterable custom linkedlist

Tags: java, foreach, linked-list, iterator, iterable

i am writing a LinkedList class as part of an assignment.
LinkedList.java:

LinkedList class: http://pastebin.com/KyKM3hP2

i am trying to get foreach working with my class.

```
LinkedList<LinkedList> ListA = new LinkedList<>();
LinkedList<String> ListB = new LinkedList<>();

ListB.append("Test1");
ListB.append("Test2");
ListB.append("Test3");

ListA.append(ListB);

//this works fine
for (String i : ListB){
    //do something with i
}
//this does not
for (String i : ListA.index(0)){
    //do something with i
}

//both the above loops should interate over ListB
//but only the first one does
```

Comment: It needs to be `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to change the declaration of `ListA` to something like this

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> ListA = new LinkedList<>();
for (String i : ListA.index(0)){
//do something with i 
}
```

if you want to get all strings in  `ListA` then do it this way.

```
   for (List lis : YourList){
     for(String s : lis){
      //System.out.println(s);
     }
    }
```

if your `linkedList` contains  `LinkedList` of `LinkedLists` of `Strings` then you have to use 2 enhanced `for loops`.

if you are using java 8 you can do it like this.

```
       Yourlist.forEach(templist ->{
       templist.forEach(s ->{
            System.out.println(s);
        });
        });
```

Comment: this is not the issue.

Comment: edited the post. by the way you have edited your question after i post the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This is in fact the solution to the problem I was having. Sorry about that, I was rushed before and did not read your answer carefully enough.